# Simple javascript problem - onMouseOver div background change

Tags: javascript, image, background

I used [this](http://mckennedy.org/blog/2009/02/25/javascript-onmouseover-link-change-divs-background-image/) code to make a nav in which onMouseOver, the neighboring div's background changes to a corresponding image.

However, I amended the code to reflect the multiple navigation buttons I needed.  This is probably where I went wrong.  Also, I am working in a ColdFusion environment on Sitemaker CMS. This could also be a problem.

Here's the code.

```
<script>
function changeStyle1() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/contractingbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle2() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/procurementbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle3() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/distributionbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle4() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/printingbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle5() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/custompacksbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle6() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/businessdevelopmentbanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyle7() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/sustainabilitybanner.jpg');
}
function changeStyleBack() {
document.getElementById('banners').style.backgroundImage = url('images/banners/laundrybanner.jpg');
}</script>
```

---

```
<div id="banners">
&nbsp;
</div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a id="contractingservices" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle1()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()">Contracting Services</a></li>
<li><a id="procurement" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle2()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()" >Procurement &amp; Data Management</a></li>
<li><a id="distribution" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle3()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()">Distribution</a></li>
<li><a id="printing" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle4()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()" >Printing</a></li>
<li><a id="laundry" href="body.cfm?id=1">Laundry</a></li>
<li><a id="custompacks" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle5()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()" >Custom Packs</a></li>
<li><a id="businessdevelopment" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle6()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()" >Business Development</a></li>
<li><a id="sustainability" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle7()"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack()" >Sustainability</a></li>
```

How do I fix this code to make it operational or find another JavaScript or jQuery solution?  I've searched and search only to come up with dozens of same-div JS background changers, which can easily be replicated with CSS.

Comment: On another note, that's a lot of redundant code. Might I suggest instead of having 8 `changeStyle` functions, reduce them to one paramaterized function? You could then pass a parameter noting which style to change to, e.g. `function changeStyle(imagePath)`

Comment: try to put **;** inside **"**. like **onmouseover="changeStyle1();"**

Comment: Your functions only affects the element with de "banners" id... you should change this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this (using jQuery, for example):

```
var styles = {
  'style-1': 'images/banner/....png',
  'style-2': 'images/banner/....png',
  // And so on...
}

function change_style(id)
{
  // Here you should check if 'id' is a valid style id
  // and if everything looks great,
  $('#banners').css('background-image', styles[id]);
}
```

And update your `<a />` tags to call this function passing the expected style

Comment: Don't know if this is what you expect as an answer, I think I just gave you another implementation.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You really don't need to write all these lines of javascript. You can accomplish your task in just a few lines of CSS code:</strike> To change the background image of another DIV, you can use a jQuery code, as in section 2 of this answer.

```
<style>
a#contractingservices{
     padding: 10px; /* Just to put the link in a big box */
     background-image : url('link/to/your/default/image');
}

a#contractingservices : hover {
     background-image : url('link/to/your/new/background/image');
}
</style>
```

Now add:

```
<a id="contractingservices" href="body.cfm?id=1">Contracting Services</a>
```

I hope you got the idea.

### Section 2 : Change BG image of another DIV by usign jQuery

```
$('a#contractingservices').mouseover(function(){
     $('#banner').css('background-image', 'link/to/new/image');
});
$('a#contractingservices').mouseout(function(){
     $('#banner').css('background-image', 'link/to/old/image');
});
```

This is what you really wanted, right?

Comment: He's trying to change the background of a different div.

Comment: Oh yes! Then, to change the background of another DIV, you can use jQuery, like:

`$('a#contractingservices').mouseover(function() {
    $('#banner').css("background-image","link/to/your/new/image");
 });`

Comment: Either way he's going to be writing some lines of javascript, haha.

Comment: Yeah, that's right! In CSS we cannot access another DIV inside from the style definition of some other DIV! Javascript is the way!

Answer (score 0):

You should make one shorthand function:

```
var d = document.getElementById('banners');

function changeStyle(image) {
d.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/banners/" + image ;
}

function changeStyleBack() {
d.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/banners/laundrybanner.jpg')";
}
```

And then call it for each of the hover images like this:

```
<div id="banners">
&nbsp;
</div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a id="contractingservices" href="body.cfm?id=1" onmouseover="changeStyle('contractingbanner.jpg');"; onmouseout="changeStyleBack();">Contracting Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or you can use jQuery's hover function so as to not use two separate functions with onmouseover and onmouseout to achieve this. Read more about that [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover).